# how to link <bsd/stdio.h> in cmake to use funopen()

Tags: linux, cmake, stdio, bsd

I am using Ubuntu, and I want to use `funopen()`, but this function is in BSD system only. So I install libbsd

```
sudo apt-get install libbsd-dev
```

after that, I can include  and I see the `funopen()` in this header file. But cannot compile.
I try use this in CMakeLists.txt, but no use:

`find_package(bsd)`

I think the param is not `bsd`, how can I do it?

[UPDATED] do as @Alu suggestion, still not work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(myProject)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
set(DIR_TO_LIB_HEADERS, /usr/include/bsd)
set(DIR_TO_BSD_LIB_FILE, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so)
include_directories(${DIR_TO_LIB_HEADERS})
add_executable(myProject ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(myProject ${DIR_TO_BSD_LIB_FILE})
```

with error:

```
undefined reference to `funopen'
```

Comment: The error says that your compiler doesn't find the definition of the method. So either the header file doesnt define the method or the wrong header will be referenced. Try including `bsd/stdio.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32 bit OS:

```
set(DIR_TO_BSD_LIB_FILE /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${DIR_TO_BSD_LIB_FILE})
```

64 bit OS:

```
set(DIR_TO_BSD_LIB_FILE /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${DIR_TO_BSD_LIB_FILE})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think cmake doesnt provide a module for "finding"the bsd lib.
You can look [here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Using_external_libraries_that_CMake_doesn.27t_yet_have_modules_for) and try to understand how the cmake find mechanism works.

But i suggest to explicit include the directories in your cmake file. 
I think you have to use something like

```
set(DIR_TO_LIB_HEADERS /usr/include/bsd)
set(DIR_TO_BSD_LIB_FILE /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so) #or /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so on 64 bit OS
include_directories(${DIR_TO_LIB_HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${DIR_TO_BSD_LIB_FILE})
```

[Here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/precise/i386/libbsd-dev/filelist) you can find the filelisting of the lib.

Comment: sorry but I cannot find /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so, do I need install any lib else, I have installed libbsd-dev?

Comment: Try to find the files on your system. Maybe you have the x64 version installed.

Comment: Maybe I found some old version of Lib bsd. Google which files will be installed when installing libbsd

Comment: I found it, but still cannot run, I have updated the question

Comment: finally I found your answer problem, remove the comma in SET. thanks :)